# Не работают js скрипты на некоторых ios

Tags: javascript, iphone, корзина

Здравствуйте. Такая интересная ситуация. Интернет-магазин, cms osstore 2.1. Некорректно работает всплывающая корзина на некоторых  iphone (6 и 5) причем именно на некоторых, на двух моделях 6 iphone может быть по разному - в одном все ок, на другом не работать. На мобильных с ОС Android, Windows phone все хорошо. На браузерах пк chrome, opera, explorer, mozilla, safari все хорошо. В safari режим совместимости также отрабатывает хорошо.

Подскажите, как можно выловить ошибки в моей ситуации без телефона?

магазин diskontshina.by

Comment: Попробовать виртуальные машины и эмуляторы?

Comment: ipadian - все хорошо, корзина работает. Такое подозрение, что может быть дело в путях для скриптов. Разница между <script src="catalog/view/javascript/ocdev_smart_cart/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?v=1.1.1" type="text/javascript"></script> и <script src="/catalog/view/javascript/ocdev_smart_cart/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js?v=1.1.1" type="text/javascript"></script> есть ?

Comment: @Matiush есть. Первый указан относительно текущей страницы, второй относительно корня сайта

Answer (score 1):

В общем, программные эмуляторы толку никакого не дают, только на реальных устройствах можно увидеть ошибку... И то, не на всех. В моей ситуации с корзиной вопрос решился правильным упорядочиванием подключаемых js скриптов. Сначала идут скрипты, необходимые для работы движка и модулей магазина, затем следует подключать собственные. Оговорюсь, такой баг вылез лишь при тестировании на НЕКОТОРЫХ iphone... На android устройствах особой разницы нет, где подключать пользовательские скрипты - на проверенных мною android устройствах все работало корректно. Как и в десктопных браузерах

Comment: Вот проблемный код https://jsfiddle.net/qpff4td2/14/

Comment: в десктопных браузерах отрабатывает. safari iphone 6 или 4, причем на НЕКОТОРЫХ, не работает. Подскажите, куда смотреть...